# Generate UNIX time for certain date in Python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime, epoch

I am new at python and I am trying to generate the same epoch time for entire day using datetime and time modules. So far I am not able to succeed. I have tried the same thing in javascript.

Following is code for it

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toDateString();
var myDate = new Date(n);
var todays_date = myDate.getTime()/1000.0;
console.log(todays_date)
```

How can I do it in python?
Please help. thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show some examples of what you expect to get as a result?

Comment: sort-of addresses this question but is very confusing to newcomers / overloaded / partly outdated in my opinion: [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python/8778548#8778548)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get seconds since the epoch for a given `date` object, you can create a datetime object from the date's timetuple (hour, minutes, seconds = 0), set the time zone if required and call the `timestamp()` method:

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timezone

unix_time = datetime(*date.today().timetuple()[:6], tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
# 1603929600.0 for 2020-10-29
```

For the example, I use date.today() which you can replace with any other `date` object. You can obtain the date object of any datetime object using `datetime_object.date()`.

Note: I'm using tzinfo=UTC here, which is arbitrary / assumes that the input date also refers to UTC. Replace with the appropriate time zone object if needed; for that see [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html). To exactly mimic your javascript code snippet, set `tzinfo=None`.

Comment: @RoDev: glad I could help. I've modified the title of your question a bit, for better findability. Check if that is ok for you.

Comment: sure, the title is okay

Answer (score 0):

Im kind of confused by what exactly it is that you want. [Here is a helpful link.](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-time/#:%7E:text=The%20Python%20time()%20function,00%3A00%3A00%20UTC.)

Does the below do what you want?

```
import time

current_time = time.time() // 86400  # second in a day
print(current_time)  # returns 18564.0 i.e. the number of days since Unix epoch
```

Comment: Not exactly...The time() will change and so does the epoch

Comment: Ok, sorry if that didn't help. I tried to avoid that by using `//` (floor division) but oh well.

Comment: It's okay. you are close to what I want but not exactly

Comment: if you modify this as `(time.time() // 86400)*86400`, it is actually a pretty cool solution to get the *current date's UNIX time*

Comment: If the question is unclear then please do not answer it. There are other questions you could be answering.